# Why is there a state which is annihilated by two different operators with same absolute Fourier index?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fermions, boundary-conditions

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposed a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring. To compute the complexity of the algorithm the authors computed the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the 
adiabatic Hamiltonian.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits in the $z$ axis.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

Then the authors start the steps of Jordan-Wigner transformation. The fermionic operators are defined as follows.

$$
b_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_-^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
\\
b^\dagger_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_+^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
$$
where
$$
\sigma_{\pm} = \sigma_x \pm i \sigma_y
$$.

After reexpressing the adiabatic Hamiltonian using the fermionic operators the authors takes the Fourier transform of the fermionic operators.

$$\beta_p =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b_j$$
where $p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)$.

Right after Eq. 4.17, the authors assume the following.

For each $p > 0$ let $|\Omega_p\rangle$ be the state annihilated by both $\beta_p$ and $\beta_{−p}$ , that is, $\beta_p |\Omega_p\rangle = \beta_{−p} |\Omega_p\rangle = 0$.

**My questions:**

Why is there a state which is annihilated by two different operators with same absolute Fourier index?

Comment: Your question isn't posed well.  There are many states which are annihilated by those operators.  The proper question should by "why is there a state which is annihilated by both $\beta_p$ and $\beta_{-p}$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, I have updated it accordingly.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, can we say that both $\beta_p$ and $\beta_{-p}$ are acting on the wavepacket of same energy as the absolute value of the momentum is same. So,  both operators annihilate the same state.

Comment: As far as I can see all the $\beta_p$ are independent fermionic operators, so there will be even a state which is annihilated by *all* of them (essentially, the vacuum state). It feels that the problem the way you describe it is underspecified.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, could you please tell what more information is needed here?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just saying that there are *lots* of states with that property, so I would imagine that the authors have more conditions in mind.  Also, I have to admit that the number of overlapping questions you ask on that paper seems a little bit out of control to me ... I really think you need to find someone to talk to in person about that.

Comment: ... well, if you read the paper, you notice that they first say that they will restrict to the subspace where only $\beta_p$ and $\beta_{-p}$ act.  $|\Omega_p\rangle$ is meant to act on that subspace only, in which case it is indeed unique.